# How to dynamically reorder rows based on input in renderDataTable in R Shiny?

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I'm asking here because I searched elsewhere and couldn't find an answer.

I'm wondering if/how you can reorder the rows of a datatable using input from R Shiny. The example below actually regenerates the table as the input changes, but I'm hoping that given a change in input, the same action as clicking the relevant sort button would happen. Any ways to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

```
library(shiny)

ui = shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Examples of DataTables'),
  sidebarPanel(

    radioButtons('var', 'Variable to sort by',
                 c(mpg='mpg',
                   cyl='cyl'),
                 'cyl')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput("mytable")
  )
)
)

server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$mytable = renderDataTable({
    mtcars[order(mtcars[,input$var]),]
  }, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE, LengthMenu = c(5, 25, 50), pageLength = 25))

})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Hm, everytime your input changes the table will be newly rendered, I'm not sure how it would work otherwise, code below with reactive is the same as above computing wise. I'm relying on the DT package  to filter/order and you can use jquery with shiny bindings for some interactivity. See https://github.com/rstudio/DT for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `reactive` function in your server, otherwise it wont react. I've also change `=` to `<-` which is more of a convention in `R`

```
library(shiny)

ui <-  shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Examples of DataTables'),
  sidebarPanel(

    radioButtons('var', 'Variable to sort by',
                 c(mpg='mpg',
                   cyl='cyl'),
                 'cyl')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput("mytable")
  )
)
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  sortTable <- reactive({
    mtcars[do.call(order, mtcars[as.character(input$var)]),]
  })

  output$mytable <- renderDataTable({
    sortTable()
  }, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE, LengthMenu = c(5, 25, 50), pageLength = 25))

})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thanks @amwill04 for your answer but the above code does the same actions as what I posted originally. I'm hoping that changing the input (clicking radio buttons) will somehow mimic the action of pressing the sorting arrows on the datatable. 

So for example if you've changed it to be "Show 5 entries" in the Shiny app, then clicking on the radio button wouldn't change this... and do the aesthetically pleasing highlight of the column being sorted.

Comment: @ShilaGhazanfar I suspect you will struggle with all that without building the table yourself. Apologise misread the question.